# grpc-java async client (with grpc C++ async server)

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

C++ Async describes how to create an async server and a corresponding async client to communicate with it. I have managed to create this in Microsoft Viual Studio.

I now need a java client to speak to the C++ server - I am unable to find a Java equivalent client (to C++) to communicate with C++.

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"Async" is part of the language-specific API; it isn't part of the RPC type. So you can use any sort of Java client to access your C++ Async server.

Java offers three API styles: async (StreamObserver), blocking, and Future (Guava's ListenableFuture). You can reference the [quick start](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/java/) or [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples) for starting with grpc-java

Comment: Thanks Eric. The problem is - I tried using a standard blocking Java client against the async C++ server and I got UNIMPLEMENTED. I will post in more information (in an airport lounge at the mo) shortly. I wondered if the async C++ service requires the Java client to pass in details such as CompletionQueue which is obviously absent in the Java API (since it is API specific, as you mentioned).

Comment: UNIMPLEMENTED generally means the grpc service/method isn't implemented by the server. So that's unrelated to "async" and the Java API. Common problems are: the client is talking to the wrong server, the server forgot to register that specific grpc service, and that one _method_ is unimplemented by the server but other methods for the same service are available.

Comment: I went back to the basic greeter example. Sever is C++ compiled and running on Windows with MS Visual Studio 19 . I can see the Java greeter client work against this. The reason I an looking at this is because in the non-async method, two simultaneous client calls were corrupting the back end process (I am pricing Trades and Quantlib classes were corrupting). Seems as if two calls were joing the same thread. I was hoping that async would give me better process control and separation on the C++ side. Looks good - so far. Thanks for the assistance, appreciated.

Comment: I ran a test with three Java clients hammering the one C++ server in async mode. Each client is executing a pricing call one thousand times. In most runs, the clients exit gracefully, but in some instance - I keep seeing this:

Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address already in use: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50051
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information
...
I see no exception on the C++ server side. I am unable to fathom an explanation.